# Ubuntu unity Video/Music/Picture lens - Settings for locations?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, unity-dash

If you are like me have a lot of media you will tend to have this on a few dedicated disks in your systems or external.

What I wish to be able to do is search pictures/videos/music from the unity dash but locate all my media spread over a number of locations.

At the moment by default the dash will only search the home folder locations for the above with no simple way to change the paths where it looks.

Anyone know how to set folder locations for the dash search?

Thanks,

Murph

Answer (score 0):

Mount all your drives and then edit by typing the following line into a terminal window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Comment: should that have the same result as if I manually mount them and then the dash should know about them?